# Как изменить обозначение строки при создании csv файла в python

Tags: python, csv

Создаю csv файл, и нужно реализовать возможность пользователю менять обозначение строки, строки могут быть обозначены или одинарной кавычкой `'`, или двойной `"`. Пробовал так, но потом понял что это не тот параметр.

```
        if context['schema'].string_character == '"':
            writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=context['schema'].column_sep, quotechar='"')
        else:
            writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter=context['schema'].column_sep, quotechar="'")
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Да вроде тот параметр

Comment: @CrazyElf как я понял, оно применяется только тогда, когда в строке есть какой-то спецсимвол, например дефис, а когда просто пробел, то нет

Comment: Попробуйте вместе с параметром `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`

Comment: @CrazyElf спасибо, помогло